# Determine row size in SQL Server for data and index

Tags: sql-server, indexing

Since I am flushing in a lot of data into a table on daily basis, I am trying to calculate the index and data *Bytes per row* size, and based on research below is the script that I have come across to identify the  data byte size per row:

```
declare @table nvarchar(128);  
declare @idcol nvarchar(128);  
declare @sql nvarchar(max);  
   
--initialize those two values  
set @table = '[Person].[AddressType]'  
set @idcol = 'AddressTypeID, Name'  
set @sql = 'select ' + @idcol + ' , (0'  
   
-- This select statement collects all columns of a table and calculate datalength  
select @sql = @sql + ' + isnull(datalength(' + name + '), 1)'  
from sys.columns where object_id = object_id(@table)  
set @sql = @sql + ') as RowSize from ' + @table + ' order by rowsize desc'  
   
-- Execute sql query   
exec (@sql)
```

Th above script suffices the requirement of calculating the data bytes per row. However I am not sure how to calculate the bytes per row for an index.

These are the indexes defined on the table:

[image]

Comment: If you want to keep using the same kind of logic, you can get a table's indexes, and the columns on those indexes, from the sys.indexes and sys.index_columns DMV's.

Comment: @allmhuran I am not specifically looking for any specific logic to be processed, I am just looking to get the Bytes per row in indexes that I have been setup which can be helpful to figure the index size for the next 90 days.

Comment: What I mean is that you can keep using the same kind of query construction (using `isnull(datalength(<columnname>))`, where you populate the `<columname>` using data gathered from `sys.indexes` and `sys.index_columns` and `sys.columns`, instead of just using `sys.columns` by itself.

Answer (score 1):

For non clustered index you can use this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/estimate-the-size-of-a-nonclustered-index?view=sql-server-ver15

For clustered index you can use this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/relational-databases/databases/estimate-the-size-of-a-clustered-index?view=sql-server-ver15